# Django при сохранении модель выдает ошибку "Пожалуйста, исправьте ошибки ниже."

Tags: django, django-admin

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой в django с правами пользователя.

Для юзера с группой в которую не входит возможность редактировать модели указные в inlines. При сохранении от лица юзера, выбивается ошибка "Пожалуйста, исправьте ошибки ниже." Но при этом ни какое из полей не подсвечивается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хитрым трюком при изменении прав и сохранив модель без прегезагрузки страницы мне удалось увидеть эти ошибки. Как тогда понимать что эти поля пустые, если на первом скриншоте видно что поля не пустые?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И соответственно перезагрузив страницу с all правами, все поля заполненные, и модель сохраняется без проблем. Но мне надо огранчить возможность удалять и изменять inlines модели для пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста, вылечить данный баг!(

Если нужны будут дополнительные сведения пишите предоставлю, но ни каких проблем в коде я не встречаю.

## UPDATE

## models.py

```
# Product stock

class Stock(models.Model):
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", verbose_name="№ Наклданой")
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата поступления")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Поступление'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Поступления'
    ordering = ["-pk"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.invoice



class StockProduct(models.Model):
    Stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Накладная", null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Модель")
    value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Количество товара", default=0)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Дверь'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Двери'

def __str__(self):
    return self.product.title

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model = Product.objects.filter(pk=self.product.pk).first()
    model.value = model.value + self.value
    model.save()
    super(StockProduct, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class StockMDF(models.Model):
     Stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Накладная", null=True)
     mdf = models.ForeignKey(MDF, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="МДФ панель")
     value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Количество товара", default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.mdf.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'МДФ панель'
    verbose_name_plural = 'МДФ панели'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model = MDF.objects.filter(pk=self.mdf.pk).first()
    model.value = model.value + self.value
    model.save()
    super(StockMDF, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


 class StockLockCylinder(models.Model):
    Stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Накладная", null=True)
    lockcylinder = models.ForeignKey(LockCylinder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Цилиндр замка")
    value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Количество товара", default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.lockcylinder.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'цилиндр замка'
    verbose_name_plural = 'цилиндры замков'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model = LockCylinder.objects.filter(pk=self.lockcylinder.pk).first()
    model.value = model.value + self.value
    model.save()
    super(StockLockCylinder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


class HideAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    get_model_perms = lambda self, req: {}


class StockProductAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = StockProduct
    extra = 1


class StockMDFAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = StockMDF
    extra = 1


class StockLockCylinderAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = StockLockCylinder
    extra = 1


class StockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['date_create']
    inlines = (StockProductAdmin, StockMDFAdmin, StockLockCylinderAdmin)


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Maker, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(SizeDoor, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(LockCylinder, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(MDF, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, admin.ModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Stock, StockAdmin)
```

UDPATE 20.12.18

Данная проблема возникает с любой моделью, которая, указана как StackedInline также такая проблема возникает у моделей StackedInline с полем read only.

Version Info:
   Django - 2.1.3

Comment: Очевидно, ваш хитрый трюк не сработал и выдал бред. Покажите код модели и код админки

Comment: Да и вообще сведите проблему в [mcve]. Если проблема воспроизводится при выкидывании всяких дверей-замков с оставлением единственного инлайна с минимумом полей в моделях - значит выкиньте всё лишнее и покажите минимальный код, он ускорит решение вопроса

Comment: @andreymal Минимальный воспроизводимый сильно зависим с другими системами, придется вывалить тонну кода( Проблемные места выложил
Хитрый трюк был намечаен на выявление проблемы, и он показал что по какой то причине readonly модели учитывается в валидаторе при сохранении.
Права на добавление и просмотор моделий у Юзера есть, а удаление и редактирование нет. Проблема возникает при таких условиях