# Django, сделать добавленные в StackedInline поля read only но оставить возможность добавлять новые

Tags: python, django

возникли проблемы с правами в django админ, [тему написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914450/django-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5) но видимо ни кто с таким не встречался, по этому интересует возможность без прав убрать возможность редактирования добавленных модели StackedInline.
[image: имж 1]
На данный момент красным выделено то что добавлено а фиолетовым то что можно добавить. Если я задаю read only полям, то соответственно и те что добавлены становятся не редактируемыми, и те что по идеи можно добавить, так же становятся не активными.

То есть для меня является задачью сделать выделенное красным не редактируемым, а фиолетовому оставить свою функциональность.
Так получается сделать если я убираю права на возможность редактирования у пользователя:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если я сохраняю модель, то вылезает ошибка, “Пожалуйста, исправьте ошибки ниже.”, как описанная [по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914450/django-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом никакие поля не выделяются. 
За ранее благодарю за оказанную помощь!

Comment: Придумал 1 способ, но скорее всего он костыльный: На js убирать возможность редактирования этих полей.

Answer (score 2):

```
class SomeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SomeModel

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: Это действительно работает, но возникает опять же ошибка "Пожалуйста, исправьте ошибки ниже." И данные в новом добавленом поле не сохраняются. А поля с ошибкой не подсвечиваются